# An x264-encoded video only with P frames and a different video for I frame

Tags: encoding, codec, x264

Suppose I have 5 frames, I encode first one as the I or reference frame and all other as P frames in one video using x264 codec.

In this case, is it possible to have 2 videos, one only with an I frame and another frame only with 4 P frames?

To decode all 4 P frames, I require the first I frame video but can we construct the videos in this way?

Comment: Sure? They won’t be playable until you reverse the process, but you can write anything you want to any number of files, named whatever you want.

Comment: can you please tell me which part of x264 encoder I need to change to separate the I frame and P frame videos and store those differently.

Comment: The part that writes the file to the disk. You can check the keyframe flag in the picture out structure.

Comment: @szatmary, I wrote that part to disk but while reading the configuration of that file using ffmpeg (ffmpeg -i Pframe.mp4) its showing error [NULL @ 00000157a75d3380] [IMGUTILS @ 0000000c8cdfebd0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[h264 @ 00000157a75d3380] Invalid NAL unit size (-30000 > 38081).
[h264 @ 00000157a75d3380] Error splitting the input into NAL units. can u please tell me why this error is showing?

Comment: How are you packing the x264 output?